# Where can I find the best mage robes for a lvl 18?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Just hoping to find out exactly where I can go to find great mage robes, hooded or unhooded.

Comment: Hi @Barry, your question is rather localized, even though the answer goes a long of giving a more general explanation. Instead of asking for a specific robe for a specific level, you should focus about how to decide whether an item is useful for your level. As to where to find such an object, the game is so large that there's no best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well its very much dependent on what magic you use and what your enchanting level is (i will assume you don't have a high enchanting level). your best bet is to finish the College of Winterhold story line at the end you can archmage robes which i used for ages until i got level 100 in enchanting.The arch mage robes have 15% spells reduction for all schools 50 magicka increase and 100% increase to magicka regeneration rate.

if you want the best possible mage armor i would recommend getting to level 100 in enchanting it takes a while but allows you to cast spells for free(enchanting 4 items with 25% destruction spell cost makes all spells free).

Comment: Great tip about stacking enchantments